# Create new tag [stripe] for questions about the Stripe payment processor

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I'd like to create a tag for questions related to the [Stripe](https://stripe.com) payment processor. I work for Stripe, and we'd like to be able to answer people's [questions about Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146641/how-do-i-include-stripe-library-with-google-app-engine) on SO.

[Searching for questions about Stripe](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=stripe) results in a lot of noise because it's such a common word, so it would be nice to be able to tag them so we can subscribe to the tag. While there is an existing tag [stripes](/questions/tagged/stripes), it is totally unrelated.

We won't be directing people to SO (we have our own support chat room and [answers website](https://answers.stripe.com) for that), but it would be nice to answer the questions of people who come to SO on their own.

Adding some links to other questions since they don't fit in the comments:

Other questions involving Stripe:

- [Using Stripe with Devise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9628359/using-stripe-with-devise)
- [Best payment gateways and Rails gems for secure payments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160490/what-is-the-payments-system-for-99designs-ugallery-look-like-what-plugins-gems)
- [Stripe Webhook on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627580/stripe-webhook-on-rails)
- [Using Stripe webhooks with Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371566/using-stripe-webhooks-with-rails)
- [Integrate nodejs with ruby for payment processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900500/integrate-nodejs-with-ruby-for-payment-processing)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592854/how-do-i-use-stripe-in-wordpress-by-having-a-form-write-an-entry-to-a-mysql-data
- [iOS - Integrating credit card payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762096/ios-integrating-credit-card-payments)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882044/australian-alternatives-to-stripe
- [Which payment provider is advisable for startup e-commerce business: PayPal or Stripe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526493/which-payment-provider-is-advisable-for-startup-e-commerce-business-paypal-or-s)
- [Need ideas on implementing a secure payments page (HTTPS) on GAE (using Stripe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436823/need-ideas-on-implementing-a-secure-payments-page-https-on-gae-using-stripe)
- [Stripe.js / stripe.php - All card errors work (expiry, cvc, incorrent #) except for declined card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706128/stripe-js-stripe-php-all-card-errors-work-expiry-cvc-incorrent-except)

Stripe was in private beta from January 2010, launched publicly in September 2011, and processes payments for such companies as [10gen](http://10gen.com), [appsumo](http://appsumo.com), [giftrocket](http://giftrocket.com), [mongohq](http://mongohq.com), [xamarin](http://xamarin.com), [MoMA](http://moma.org), and the City of Portland.

Comment: As Stack Overflow already has [tag:stripes], it is not possible to create [tag:stripe]; I am not sure if moderators can create it, if there is the need.

Comment: Well, I got this message when I tried to create it: `Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
Creating the new tag [stripe] is not allowed since the tag [stripes] already exists. If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.` so here I am.

Comment: Cant you call it something like [stripe-payment-processor-api]?

Comment: That seems to target an awfully limited number of developers. That doesn't necessarily make it a bad suggestion, but unless the stripe development or support team monitors SO the askers will likely end up with a bunch of unanswered questions. This could make either the third party look bad (outstanding open questions about their API is never a good thing) or (less likely) could look bad for SO. Either way, you may want to solicit *them* to have the tag added to make sure they're okay with the extra support leg.

Comment: I work for Stripe. We're looking to answer questions on SO. [stripe-payment-processor-api] is pretty gross. It would be nice to have something more analogous to [paypal] or [braintree].

Comment: @alberge - Please add that to your question so anyone answering can know your intentions.

Comment: As a side note, if you are going to start answering questions related to your product you should add a short note in your bio stating you are an employee. This will help Moderators should your answers get flagged for possible spam or excessive promotion.

Comment: Yep, I'll probably do that. I've just been writing that disclaimer in the answer itself so far.

Answer (score 4):

Any way you look at this, you're going to end up with something that's not *just* the word "stripe." If we added a stripe tag, all the people who don't realize what it's actually for are going to use it as a meta-tag. People looking for "zebra-stripe" solutions are going to tag it with stripe *just* because it's there. I'm actually very surprised this hasn't happened on [stripes](/questions/tagged/stripes) most frequently, or maybe the community is just really good at cleaning up the unrelated questions.

I would recommend something like [stripe-payments](/questions/tagged/stripe-payments). It's shorter but still indicates that it is the **Stripe** API for **Payment** Processing, and it won't attract unrelated questions. Services like PayPal and BrainTree don't need attachments because those aren't common words that are used in programming. When you hear PayPal, you either know instantly that it's about the payment processor, or you have absolutely no idea what it is (if you haven't ever heard of the service).

However, before you go creating the tag, you need an audience that is going to use the tag. You've only found one question so far that could be tagged with it. Tags that only have one question are automatically purged after 6 months anyways, so you'll need some more ground to bounce from in order for this to work out. After all, this isn't a place where you can dump all of your support questions like Facebook tried to do.

Did you guys just start up recently? Your about page doesn't mention anything about when the company was founded or a timeline/history. Obviously it's been around since at least November 16, 2011 since there was a question about it then. How wide is your customer/user base?

Comment: I edited my question to respond to some of those points. Your point about the generic name is a good one, but evidence suggests that it hasn't happened with [stripes]. Why not create the [stripe] tag and change it later if it's problematic?

Comment: The idea is to *prevent* it happening in the first place. If you've found a good number of examples, I don't see why you couldn't give it a try, but I doubt anyone is going to support creating [stripe] as a tag. You should really go with [stripe-payments] or similar.